# Whitelist filter with k8s Gateway API GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-gateway-api

k8s Ingress allows to filter IPs through annotation **nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range**.

How can i to do the same through **Gateway Api** in GCP? https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/gateway-api

I have not found any exemples of such behaviour for **Gateway Api**

Comment: I don't think you can filter IP or IP range in Gateway API, but you can filter based on header.

while its unusual but in case if you have one more layer before Gateway API endpoint, then you may be able to use first layer add header to filter in second layer (gateway API).

Comment: if you have CDN or similar layer before Gateway API endpoint, usually CDN will add IP to request header, which you can use to filter as static value, but not range.

Answer (score 0):

Allow listing IP addresses is enforced via Cloud Armor policies.  For example, you can use a rule like `inIpRange(origin.ip, '198.51.100.0/24')` in a [Cloud Armor security policy](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies).

With the Gateway API, you can then use gateway policies to [attach a Cloud Armor policy to your Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/configure-gateway-resources#configure_cloud_armor):

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: GCPBackendPolicy
metadata:
  name: my-backend-policy
  namespace: lb-service-namespace
spec:
  default:
    securityPolicy: example-security-policy
  targetRef:
    group: ""
    kind: Service
    name: lb-service
```

Comment: Thank for the response. I have a question. If i’m not mistaken, GCPGatewayPolicy can be attached to the Gateway resource what means that this setting will be applied to the Gateway resource and affects all HTTPRoute resources, but on the other hand, GCPBackendPolicy can only be attached to Service resources. So my question how GCPBackendPolicy will be connected to my Gateway resource? Or should i create a separate GCPBackendPolicy for each my Service that has it’s own HTTPRoute? I wanna apply whitelisting to all routes associated with Gateway.